# Obfuscating a url

Tags: asp.net, url

I'm working on an asset management website where in whenever an asset is issued to a user the system would send an email notification with a url in it that would show the user all the assets issued to him. I could have used the query string to pass the user ID but again people could abuse it to view assets issued to other users. My client doesn't wants the user to authenticate themselves when they click on the link. So i need something that would hide the parameters being passed in the query string or at least make them obscure. I've read about url encoding, GUID etc. but i'm not sure what to do. I'm just a beginner. Please pardon my ignorance and point me in the right direction.

Comment: This seems like a really really REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @asawyer how else should i do it ? I was hoping to have a users login and then capture their EID. But my i've been asked to avoid the log in page.

Comment: Is the site internal or external? If it's internal and on a windows domain you could use Windows authentication, then use their NT credentials on the incoming request to ID them.

Comment: Is this meant to be a permalink, or a one-time-use code?

Comment: You don't need to obscure it - just make it a sufficiently large block of random data as a query string parameter and store that in the DB as the user's access token or API key. Reset it every time they change their password, or every X days, or provide them a UI to generate a new one. Lots of sites do this e.g. github, JIRA, especially for authenticated access to RSS feeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken what you have said, that you're just a beginner, and assuming that this will be public, you can do the easiest way:

Create a new table in your database and called for example `tbl_links`, as columns just add 3

```
user_id (foreigner key to the user table)
guid (primary key, unique)
settings (nvarchar(250)
```

When you need to send an email, create a new row for the user, for example:

```
Guid guid = Guid.New();
String settings = "date_from:2012/01/01;date_to:2013/01/01";
```

And insert it one the database, where the link that you put in the email, should have the guid, for example, http://domain.com/info/?g=....

You could append Json to that `settings` column and parse it into an object again in the code, ask a new question if you want to take this route.

I personally use a security algorithm to pass only the `user_id` but you did said you're a beginner, so I only showed you the easy and still valid way.

---

**P.S.** for security reasons, you should say in the email that your link is only valid for the next 4 hours or so you can prevent people from generating GUIDs in order to try and get some information.... Simple add a `create_date` column of type `datetime` and use that to see if the link already expired or not...

Comment: How exactly would i use the settings column ??

Comment: that's up to you, the `settings` column can be the same string as you would pass in your link and then, using splits, you can get each value... if you always need the same parameters, let's imagine, `date_from` and `date_to`, you can actually create a column to hold each value, but as I said, I would prefer to hold in the `settings` column the representation of a Json string and then maybe a column to hold the type of my object and for that you can reuse this in any part of your app, not only to send emails, as you can image that in 6 month you need one more value... no need to update the db.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've implemented your idea and is working now. Thanks again for your help. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

For obscuring URL parameters, you want to use a [modified Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications). Please keep in mind that obscurity is not security, and Base64 encoding something does not in any way make anything secure.

If you're intending to use this for authentication purposes, I think you should reconsider. Look into public key encryption and digital signatures as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to secure access to a URL is not the right approach.  Give the urls away freely and authenticate your users instead.

I would also highly recommend using SSL for serving up this data.

Security through obscurity fails 100% of the time once the obscurity is not longer obscure.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add some prefix and suffix to the id and the encrypt that string. Something like this:

```
static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
{
  byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
        = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
  string returnValue
        = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
  return returnValue;
}

static public string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
{
  byte[] encodedDataAsBytes
      = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
  string returnValue =
     System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
  return returnValue;
}

string prefix = "lhdsjñsdgñdfj";
string suffix  = "dfknsfñn3ih";

var strToEncode = prefix + "|" + id + "|" + suffix;
var encoded =  EncodeTo64(str);

var decoded = DecodeFrom64(encoded).Split('|');

if( decoded.length != 3 || decoded[0] != prefix || decoded[2] != suffix )
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("id");

var decodedId = decoded[1];
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea but my website is an intranet application and i needed just basic security for my urls which is being served after i implemented balexandre's answer. Thank you for your answer.